# Run an Angular 4 and an Angular 8 App on the Same Page

Tags: angular

I've got a page (that I do not control) that runs an Angular 4 app.

I've got an Angular 8 app (that I control) which needs to run on the page with the Angular 4 app. The Angular 4 app loads first.

When I attempt to do this, I receive the following errors when the Angular 8 app attempts to load:

```
Already loaded patch: ZoneAwarePromise
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
```

I have tried editing `polyfills.ts` to only load Zone.js if it's not already loaded, but that only gets rid of the first error.

I've got a bad feeling that there is no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: any solution? Same issue here

Comment: @Septk I did find a solution. It involved the Angular 4 app putting its `ngZone` on the `window` object, and the Angular 8 app using that `ngZone` in the bootstrap.

Unfortunately this broke change detection in the Angular 8 app for anything using RxJS (subscribing to Observables, etc.). Luckily, the solution to that was just injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` into the Components, and firing `detectChanges()` manually when needed.

Far less than optimal, but far better than a rewrite using a different framework. If you have any questions, I'd be happy to assist.

Answer (score -1):

Host them separately, map their URLs to the same domain, host one of them in an iframe.

Comment: The Angular 8 app has to appear and work as an integral part of the overall page, which an iframe doesn't allow.

Answer (score -2):

One Solution can be:

1. Remove or comment out `import zone.js` from all the `polyfills.ts`
2. Add the following to your index.html:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js"></script>`